# Should we avoid the [discussion] tag?

Tags: tagging

At the moment we've got 62 questions tagged with [discussion] on meta. I believe that this tag is insignificant and should be avoided if not even removed.

- The main purpose of the meta site is discussion, so that tag is not very differentiating.
- I can see some discussion-only tagged questions regarding community wiki, badges, comments, questioning, answering, quality, FAQ or SO. They're hard to find if I look for the subject as long as they don't get the subject as tag but remain merged to discussion only.

Questions with just a single tag [discussion] should get a tag describing the topic of the discussion, at least if it's not too uncommon.

Though I can see that [discussion] is marked as required tag. Perhaps this might be changed technically.

Comment: Can we even remove the `discussion` tag?

Comment: Good point! I can see that the tag is "required". Perhaps it could serve as fallback tag if no appropriate tag could be found. I'll lower the question for from 'remove' to 'avoid'.

Comment: Non-moderators need to use one of the `bug`, `feature-request`, `discussion` and `support` tags.

Comment: Ah, ok! So for the mod it's a difference. However, at least a meaningful tag should be used additionally to mark about *what* is discussed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two points to the discussion tag:

1. It means nothing needs to be done with this question, from a site-maintenance point of view.  Because Meta is the non-developer issue-tracking database, it makes sense to enforce that there are a set of tags that non-moderators need to choose, and then you need a non-issue tag.  There could be many non-issue tags, but that risks confusion for new users.
2. It emphasises that Meta is not a Q&A site in the way that the parent site is. Discussion is bad thing on the parent site, it's fine here.

Furthe to issue tracking, it is often hard to distinguish [discussion] and [feature-request]s, except by the tag.  It's crucial there to the significance of the question.

Answer (score 5):

I agree.  Thought the "tag" box here says something like "must have one of bug|feature-request|support|discussion" so I've been using "discussion" to mean "none-of-the-above".  If that list weren't there then perhaps we wouldn't have so many tagged as "discussion".

Comment: Exactly. Questions in meta are often difficult to tag without inventing a new label.